# Datareader has rows property returns false

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to check if the username exists or not . I am using XMLHTTPREqUEST object in the html page and sending user name and password values to Default aspx page.But when I exacute the code .Nothing happens.I mean There is no exception message or anyting  after  debugging I have  noticed that connection state open but datareader's hasRows property returns false.I am sure I am able to pass query string values  into variables . And  What am i missing out Can you plase help

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.QueryString["ka"] != null && Request.QueryString["pass"] != null)
        {

            string username = Request.QueryString["ka"];
            string pass = Request.QueryString["pass"];
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=.\\sqlexpress;database=Projects;UID=sa;Password=1234");
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed) {


                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from userstable where username=@name and pass=@pass", con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", username);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", pass);




                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (dr.HasRows)
                {

                    Response.Write("exist");
                }
                else
                {

                    Response.Write("Doesntexist");
                }
                con.Close();




            }

        }


        Response.Close();

    }
```

this is Htmlpage

```
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">


       function createXHR() {

           var xhr;


           try {
               xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
           } catch (e) {

           }
           return xhr;
       }


       function signIn() {

           var xhr = createXHR();
           var username=$('#txtusername').val();
           var pass=$('#txtpass').val()

           xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){

               if(xhr!=null){

                   if(xhr.readyState==4){

                       if(xhr.status>=200 && xhr.status<300){

                           var v = $('#result').html(xhr.responseText);
                           if (v == "exist") {
                               $('#result').html("Done");
                           }
                           else if (v == "Doesntexist") {

                               $('#result').html("Error");
                           }
                           else{
                               $('#result').html(v);

                           }

                           }

                   }

               }
               else{
                   $('#result').html("Error");


               }
           }

           xhr.open("GET", "Default.aspx?ka='" + username + "&pass=" + pass, true);
           xhr.send(null);
       }
   </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="txtusername" type="text"  name="txtusername"/><br />
    <input id="txtpass" type="text"  name="txtpass"/><br />
    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="signin" onclick="signIn();" /><br />
    <div id="result" ></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Side note: Please don't store passwords in plain text.  User passwords should be hashed and you should store the hash.  There's no reason to ever be able to *read* a user's raw password.

Comment: Perhaps there's no user with the given username and password in the database? :) Also, the result from the page is most likely going to be a full fledged HTML page, so testing for `responseText` might be tricky. Why are you writing this as a page rather than as a web service?